# Is there a list of words with the -um- ending?

Tags: word-formation

Since the -um- suffix is undefined, is there any list of words that use it and say what they mean?

Answer (score 4):

Source: http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq130.html#sec13-2

**The suffix -um- is used to produce idiosyncratic derivatives from roots (most often nouns) when other suffixes are inappropriate to the purpose. Here are the most common ones:**

- butiko = a shop   butikumi = to shop
- cerbo = brain     cerbumi = rack one’s brains
- kruco = cross     krucumi = to crucify
- kubuto = elbow    kubutumi = to elbow people (in a crowd)
- malvarma = cold   malvarmumo = a cold
- mastro = master (of house, etc.)  mastrumi = attain mastery over
- nazo = nose   nazumi = to nose around, nose through
- nomo = name   nomumi = to name [to an office]
- orbito = an orbit     orbitumi = to orbit
- plena = full  plenumi = to fulfill
- polekso = thumb   poleksumi = (1) to thumb through , (2) to thumb a ride
- proksima = close  proksimuma = approximate
- vento = wind  ventumi = to fan
- vintro = winter   vintrumi = to spend the winter

**One of the most significant uses of -um- is to derive the name of an article of clothing from that of a body part:**

- brako = arm   brakumo = arm of a garment
- kolo = neck   kolumo = collar
- mano = hand   manumo = cuff (of sleeve)
  nazo = nose     nazumo = nosebag, nose-cover

Comment: I think "brakumo" also means a hug; "brakumi" = "to hug, to embrace"

Comment: @kristan Indeed. I think ‘sleeve’ is an exception to the ‘add *um* to a body part to mean the part of clothing that covers it’-rule. A sleeve is *maniko*.

Comment: The word "maniko" in Esperanto means "sleeve".  "Brakumo" means "a hug".  This is an error in Dr. Jordan's list, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

[PMEG lists a lot of UM words](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/um.html), categorized by the five main productive meanings of UM on the one hand and "diverse UM words" on the other hand. It is a more reliable source than the other ones that have been mentioned, but it doesn't have English translations, only explanations in Esperanto.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

[Thank goodness for Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_words_with_the_suffix_-um)